# zookeeper connection error in NiFi version nifi-1.2.0.3.0.0.0-453

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I have a 3 node cluster all using the NiFi version nifi-1.2.0.3.0.0.0-453. The cluster has been working fine for the last couple of weeks, however today all of a sudden one of the nodes disconnected from the cluster and won't join the cluster back. I checked the logs and the error I see is the following:

> ERROR [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Background retry gave up
>   org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:838)
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:809)
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:64)
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:267)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2017-06-27 17:54:40,179 ERROR [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Background operation retry gave up
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:728)
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:857)
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:809)
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:64)
>       at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:267)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The node itself appears to still be running but is disconnected from the cluster. I tried restarting it but the same error keeps appearing over and over again. The other two nodes in the cluster are working fine. Does anyone have any idea of what could be causing this sudden issue? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an external ZooKeeper or embedded?

Comment: I am using an external zookeeper and we verified it and seems to be working fine. If I restart the other two nodes in the cluster they join to the cluster fine. The issue is only with that one node

Comment: On the node thats the problem, is the value of nifi.zookeeper.connect.string in nifi.properties any different than on the other two? and can that node ping all the ZK addresses successfully?

Comment: yes the nifi.zookeeper.connect.string is the same for all three nodes and from that node I can ping all the ZK addresses successfully.

Comment: hmm if you started that node again, are there any other errors before this one? wondering if there is a different problem that is causing this.